# É correto o uso de "ò" hoje em dia?

Tags: preposições, contrações

Eu já vi em textos antigos e no dicionário da Priberam (sim, "Priberam" é ela; o Priberam refere-se ao **dicionário** da Priberam), porém eu não sei se seu uso é correto por ser arcaico.

A + a = à

A + o = ò

A + o = ao

Exemplo: "Foi dito ò rei que a batalha fora perdida".

Comment: «em Portugal fala-se "à" com a pronúncia de "ã"»: estás a confundir essa contração *à* (preposição a + artigo/pronome a) com o artigo *a*. A contração "à" de que falas diz-se com a aberto - como os acentos agudos e graves exigem.

Comment: ANeves, vou retirar essa afirmação minha, obrigado.

Comment: Na linguagem falada nós dizemos "vô **ò** café" o tempo todo. Agora se grafia correta, se quisermos mesmo reproduzir a fala, é *ò* ou *ó* é que eu não sei.

Comment: Vou ao café fica é o mais correto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 (Base XII: do emprego do acento grave)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990) não prevê as formas ***ò, òs***; reserva o acento grave para *à*, *àquele*, *àquela*, *àqueloutro*, *àqueloutra*, seus  plurais e a *àquilo*.

No Brasil já era assim anteriormente, tal como prescrito no [Formulário Ortográfico de 1943 (Base XII – Acentuação Gráfica, 43, 16ª)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1943).

Mas em Portugal, as formas ***ò*** e ***òs*** estavam explicitamente previstas no [Acordo Ortográfico de 1945 (artigo 24)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1945), em vigor antes do Acordo de 1990. O mesmo acontecia com “*prò*, *prà*, *pròs* e *pràs*, contracções de *pra*, redução da preposição *para*, com as quatro formas *o*, *a*, *os* e *as*”.

Concordantemente, o Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa de 2001, anterior à entrada em vigor do Acordo de 1990, traz *ò* (desenvolvo as abreviações):

> **ò** [ɔ´]. *contracção Popular*: Contracção da preposição. *a* com o artigo ou pronome demonstrativo *o*. *Indignado repetia: «Ò que se chegou!...»*

Portanto, se segues, como muita gente, a norma anterior ao atual acordo ortográfico, estás à vontade para escrever *ò fim e ò cabo* ou *pergunta ò que chegar primeiro*. Se seguires a norma atual, normalmente, nomeadamente em escrita formal ou técnica, o problema não se coloca. Tal como podemos ver escrito *foi para a praia* e ler *foi prapraia* ou mesmo *papraia*, também podemos escrever *ao fim e ao cabo* e ler *ò fim e ò cabo*. Se quiseres mesmo reproduzir por escrito esse aspeto da pronúncia — pode ser importante em poemas ou escrita expressiva — parece-me que a melhor opção é mesmo escrever *ò*. A alternativa seria [*ó* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/%C3%B3), tal como na interjeição de chamamento (*Ó João, anda cá*). Mas eu pelo menos escreveria *ò*, por analogia com *à*.

Comment: Uau, nunca esperei esta resposta... "Ó João vai ò talho", um acento para cada lado? :) Que fixe!

Comment: @ANeves, já tinhas "vem cá à mãe". O que é que te surpreendeu?

Comment: Obrigado, Jacinto. Eu me esqueci de te agradecer, desculpa.

Comment: @Schilive, ora essa. Sempre às ordens. Estive a rever, e o AO 90, Base XII - do emprego do acento grave, diz apenas: "Emprega-se o acento grave..." e depois lista os casos de *à*, *àquele*, *àqueloutro*, etc. Não diz que é exclusivamente. De qualquer modo uma lei ortográfica não pode banir uma palavra, nem privar-nos dos meios de  a escrever.

Comment: @Jacinto, disso eu não sabia. Bom saber.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o dicionário Priberam:

> ò (a + o)
> contracção
> [Arcaico]  Contracção da preposição a com o artigo ou pronome o.
>
> Confrontar: ó e oh.
> Palavras relacionadas: agorinha, torpidamente, mormente, endoado, espojadoiro, descoramento, òs.
>
> ó 1 (latim o)
> interjeição
> Palavra usada para chamar ou invocar.
>
> Confrontar: oh e ò.
>
> Ver também dúvida linguística: oh/ó.
>
> Palavras relacionadas: ò, oh, ilota, glucose, boca, queratose, alhora.
>
> ó 2
> substantivo masculino
> Nome da letra o ou O.
>
> Confrontar: ò.
>
> Palavras relacionadas: ò, ilota, glucose, azerola, babordo, queratose, oh.

"ò", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%B2 [consultado em 08-05-2020].

Comment: A pergunta era "é correto usar ó hoje em dia?", mas não me parece que isto responda. Não queres editar para que a tua resposta responda explicitamente à pergunta?